# Using function in where clause with clob parameter

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

We are using a `@NamedNativeQuery` to fetch entities from our database that are qualified by the stored procedure `flexmatch` in the where clause of a query.

This works fine in general, but when the parameter `chimeString` exceeds 4.000 characters it fails raising the following exception:

> ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

This does make sense, as 4.000 characters are Oracle's border between String and Clob.

We tried to

1. use `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy`

   ```
   return entityManager
       .createNamedQuery("Structure.findByExactMatch", Structure.class)
       .setParameter("chime", ClobProxy.generateProxy(chimeString))
       .getResultList();
   ```
2. use `javax.persistence.criteria.ParameterExpression` together with `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy`

   ```
   ParameterExpression<Clob> chimeParam = entityManager
       .getCriteriaBuilder()
       .parameter(Clob.class, "chime");
   return entityManager
       .createNamedQuery("Structure.findByExactMatch", Structure.class)
       .setParameter(chimeParam, ClobProxy.generateProxy(chimeString))
       .getResultList();
   ```

Libraries & System:

- Oracle 11g
- Hibernate 3.6.6

The find method.

```java
public List<Structure> findByExactMatch(String chimeString) {
  return entityManager
      .createNamedQuery("Structure.findByExactMatch", Structure.class)
      .setParameter("chime", chimeString)
      .getResultList();
}
```

The Structure entity.

```java
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
  @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "Structure.findByExactMatch",
    query = "SELECT id, molfile(ctab) ctab FROM structure " + 
            "WHERE flexmatch(ctab, :chime, 'all')=1",
    resultClass = Structure.class) })
public class Structure {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @Lob
  @Column(name = "CTAB")
  private String ctab;

  // getter & setter

}
```

**Edit 1** The pl/sql function, as you can see it is overloaded.

```sql
FUNCTION flexmatch(
    molobj IN BLOB, 
    querymol IN VARCHAR2,
    args IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER

FUNCTION Flexmatch(
    molobj IN BLOB, 
    querymol IN CLOB,
    args IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of trying, we gave up to solve it within Hiberante. We ran the query using SpringJDBC, which is also present in the project, and used the ID to populate a Hiberante entity. You could do this with plain old JDBC also.